# Facebook Check In Android me/feed Endpoint Not Displaying

Tags: android, facebook

Trying to checkin using the Android Facebook SDK via a GraphRequest.

Using exactly the same parameters on a request that works correctly on the equivalent iOS app.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("place","203980129774288");

GraphRequest request = new GraphRequest(
                AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                "/me/feed",
                parameters,
                HttpMethod.POST);

request.setCallback(new GraphRequest.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Facebook share onCompleted() called with: response = [" + response + "]");
                if ( response.getError() == null ) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"Success");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Facebook onCompleted() called with: error = [" + response.getError().getErrorMessage() + "]");

                }
            }
        });
request.executeAsync();
```

The post is successful but when I view it in my feed it just has a status with:

> Test User has updated his status

There is no place associated with the post. Normally a big map appears with the place's name in the status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was either posting with the Facebook test user I had created or the fact it was Facebook on a Genymotion emulator (I've installed Play Services).

When I switched to a real device and my personal Facebook account, the share appeared successfully with the map and place selected.